# efficient way to reformat/shift time series data using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series, apache-spark-sql

I want to build some time series models using spark. The first step is to reformat the sequence data into training samples. The idea is:

original sequential data (each t* is a number)

```
t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9  t10
```

desired output

```
t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6
t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7
t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8
..................
```

how to write a function in spark to do this.
The function signature should be like

reformat(Array[Integer], n: Integer)

return type is Dataframe or Vector

==========The code I tried on Spark 1.6.1 =========

```
val arraydata=Array[Double](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
val slideddata = arraydata.sliding(4).toSeq
val rows = arraydata.sliding(4).map{x=>Row(x:_*)}
sc.parallelize(arraydata.sliding(4).toSeq).toDF("Values")
```

The final line can not go through with error:

```
Error:(52, 48) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]]
    sc.parallelize(arraydata.sliding(4).toSeq).toDF("Values")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to figure out the significance of `n` as it can be used as the window size as well as the value with which it has to shift.

Hence there are both the flavours:

**If n is the window size :**

```
def reformat(arrayOfInteger:Array[Int], shiftValue: Int) ={
sc.parallelize(arrayOfInteger.sliding(shiftValue).toSeq).toDF("values")
}
```

`On REPL:`

```
scala> def reformat(arrayOfInteger:Array[Int], shiftValue: Int) ={
     | sc.parallelize(arrayOfInteger.sliding(shiftValue).toSeq).toDF("values")
     | }
reformat: (arrayOfInteger: Array[Int], shiftValue: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> val arrayofInteger=(1 to 10).toArray
arrayofInteger: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> reformat(arrayofInteger,3).show
+----------+
|    values|
+----------+
| [1, 2, 3]|
| [2, 3, 4]|
| [3, 4, 5]|
| [4, 5, 6]|
| [5, 6, 7]|
| [6, 7, 8]|
| [7, 8, 9]|
|[8, 9, 10]|
+----------+
```

**If n is the value to be shifted:**

```
def reformat(arrayOfInteger:Array[Int], shiftValue: Int) ={
val slidingValue=arrayOfInteger.size-shiftValue
sc.parallelize(arrayOfInteger.sliding(slidingValue).toSeq).toDF("values")
}
```

`On REPL:`

```
scala> def reformat(arrayOfInteger:Array[Int], shiftValue: Int) ={
     | val slidingValue=arrayOfInteger.size-shiftValue
     | sc.parallelize(arrayOfInteger.sliding(slidingValue).toSeq).toDF("values")
     | }
reformat: (arrayOfInteger: Array[Int], shiftValue: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> val arrayofInteger=(1 to 10).toArray
arrayofInteger: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> reformat(arrayofInteger,3).show(false)
+----------------------+
|values                |
+----------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] |
|[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] |
|[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] |
|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
+----------------------+
```

Comment: why I can not do "toDF"? I can only create RDD

Comment: Maybe I am using Spark 1.6.1, not 2.0

Comment: For using toDF you must create sqlContext and then import sqlContext.implicits._ then only you can use toDF

Comment: Thanks, I tried on Spark 1.6.1, but still unable to make it successful.

Comment: Can you paste your exact code! better would be a new question so that others may not find it  unethical

Comment: added, please check. Thanks.

Comment: Add this to your code : val sqlcontext=new SqlContext(sc); import sqlcontext.implicits._